# How to Set the Checkbox value inside GridView?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkbox

How to set the CheckBox value, which is located inside a Gridview ?

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gviewPermission" runat="server" 
        onrowdatabound="gviewPermission_RowDataBound" 
        onrowupdated="gviewPermission_RowUpdated" 
        onrowupdating="gviewPermission_RowUpdating">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Allow" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="Check_Allow" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Deny" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="Check_Deny" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

The check box value has to set based upon some condition....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `gviewPermission_RowDataBound` function do:

```
if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("Check_Allow")).Checked = SomeCondition;
```

Or if the condition is coming directly from the datasource you can do:

```
 <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="Check_Allow" runat="server" 
                  Checked='<%# Eval("ConditionFromDs") %>' />
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 3):

If the value of column is boolean then. Try the below code

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <center>
      <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" Checked='<%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("isChecked"))%>' runat="server"></asp:CheckBox></center>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Where "isChecked" is the column name.

Answer (score 0):

the CheckBox control has an attribute called `Checked` that works similarly to the html counterpart attribute. So set this attribute either in the aspx markup:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="Check_Allow" runat="server" Checked='<%= someCondition == true %>' />
```

or in your code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" checked='<%# bool.Parse(Eval("check").ToString()) %>'  ID="chkselet" />
  </ItemTemplate>
```

check value must be true or false