# Checkbox OnCheckedChange event with postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox, oncheckedchanged

I have a gridview with `checkbox` controls as columns and with `Autopostback='true'` for inserting to db.
 Everyting works fine except when i "*change pages*" - Postback (?)

My checked checkboxes gets unchecked when I go back to the page.

My `Page_Load` have a `!IsPostBack` and then i bound my gridview (**gwPlanning**)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGridViewPlanning();
    }
}
```

and my **code behind**:

```
protected void myCheckBox_OnCheckedChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    CheckBox myCheckBox = (CheckBox)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)myCheckBox.NamingContainer;

    string ThisWeekMinus2 = row.Cells[1].Text;
    bool status = myCheckBox.Checked;

    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [BI_Planning].[dbo].[tblPlanning] SET [This Week - 2] = @IsActive WHERE ActivityID = @ID  ", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@IsActive", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = myCheckBox.Checked;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ThisWeekMinus2;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

    }        

}
```

any idea what i'm missing?

Comment: Whats in `BindGridViewPlanning()` do you have the set values when you read from db? Probably not loading correctly to the gridview. The checkboxes are getting made but they have no initial load values so they are always not selected.

Comment: the problem for me is that the db gets updated with 'true' when the checkbox i checked but the checkbox is not checked when page is updated but the db value is still 'true'

Comment: There is already a answer given to this. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17792216/7324631). You can apply the 2nd solution.

Comment: The 2nd solution i think you mean "Checked='<%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("isChecked"))%>'" the error i get there is "String was not recognized as a valid Boolean."

Comment: to make it more clear. Please set a breakpoint on  `gwPlanning.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];`. Check the name of the bool value in the datasource. Specify this name in the Eval. And see if it works. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was just to add:

**Checked='<%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("....YourColumn...."))%>**

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" AutoPostBack="true"  Checked='<%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("....YourColumn...."))%> OnCheckedChanged="myCheckBox_OnCheckedChange" runat="server" Style="text-align: center" />
```